# Bullet point aligning to middle of wrapped text rather than top line

Tags: css

On my joomla site, if I use a bullet point for a long sentence that wraps to more than one line, the bullets point aligns to the middle of wrapped text rather than keeping flush to the top line e.g. if my text wrapped to 3 lines, the bullet point would align to the 2nd line.

I want bullet points to always align to the top line regardless of how many lines of text there are. It's hard to tell where the next point starts otherwise!

Any ideas how I can do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: can you please add your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code or a JS Fiddle, it's hard to tell, but my guess is that you have generated bullet points using a background image on the `<li>`. If you add `background-position: top` to your `<li>` in your CSS - `li { background-position: top; }`, the bullet should align top.

Personally I create custom bullets using [psuedo elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) (`:before` and `:after`) though, as they are a bit easier to position.

As the comment said though, please add your code/JS Fiddle if the above does not help.

Comment: That's enough info for me to work it out! Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Sophie No problem :-). If it solved your issue, would you be able to mark the answer as accepted (the tick icon next to an answer)? Just helps keep things tidy here :)